# Download multiple file from GitHub public repos without git

Tags: powershell, github, github-api

The public git repository  architecture looks like (https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel) :

...
Detection  
----------- ASimAuthentication 
-----------------------imAuthBruteForce.yaml
-----------------------imAuthPasswordSpray.yaml
-----------------------...
----------- ASimDNS
----------------------imDNS_Miners.yaml
---------------------- ...
----------- ...

I would like to be able to download all the .yaml files in each of the "Detection" subfolders without fully downloading the repos.
For now, I can download the file only with its exact path.

example :

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/$Author/$Name/$Branch/Detections/ASimAuthentication/imAuthBruteForce.yaml" -OutFile "$Location\imAuthBruteForce.yaml"
```

I'm looking for a method to iterate over each of my folders and perform this command recursively on all the .yaml files.

Has anyone had the same problem or has any advice for me ?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what your question is exactly. In which form do you have your `($Author, $Name, $Branch)` tuples that you would like to download? Either a simple [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1) will do, or your problem is more complicated. From what you have written, I cannot tell.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to list all the files without cloning the repo, right? There might be a way to do this using the GitHub API?

Comment: ojdo I am looking for a way to list all the files without cloning the repo
joanis Yes ! I found nothing so I finally scrape the github page by myself ! :)